# Internet over USB on BeagleBone Black

Tags: networking, dns, arm, beagleboard

I've recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 on the Beagle Bone Black. This image:

> https://rcn-ee.net/deb/flasher/raring/BBB-eMMC-flasher-ubuntu-13.04-2013-10-08.img.xz

This microcontroller allows to share internet connection between host PC (Version 12.04 (precise) (64-Bit), Kernel Linux 3.2.0-56-generic) and BeagleBone over USB, so I went for it and configured the device as follows:

BeagleBone Black:

```
ifconfig usb0 192.168.7.2
route add default gw 192.168.7.1
```

Host PC:

```
sudo su
#eth0 is my internet facing interface, eth3 is the BeagleBone USB connection
ifconfig eth2 192.168.7.1
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface eth2 -j ACCEPT
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

After that Internet Connection works itself, when I do `ping 8.8.8.8` I get the results:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=1 ttl=47 time=4.63 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=2 ttl=47 time=4.68 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=3 ttl=47 time=4.57 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_req=4 ttl=47 time=4.58 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.578/4.620/4.682/0.063 ms
```

To have DNS configured too I typed aswell `echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >> /etc/resolv.conf` but unfortunately when I do `ping google.com` I get, after few seconds of computing, `ping: unknown host google.com`

So - I know, that this solution isn't good, but for this session it could work and it doesn't. What's more, both - BBB and PC - use resolvconf. To be honest I've got no clue how to configure network using this program... I tried changing `/etc/network/interfaces` on Beagle Bone Black like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
#auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
# Example to keep MAC address between reboots
#hwaddress ether DE:AD:BE:EF:CA:FE

# WiFi Example
#auto wlan0
#iface wlan0 inet dhcp
#    wpa-ssid "essid"
#    wpa-psk  "password"

# Ethernet/RNDIS gadget (g_ether)
# ... or on host side, usbnet and random hwaddr
# Note on some boards, usb0 is automaticly setup with an init script
# in that case, to completely disable remove file [run_boot-scripts] from the boot partition
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.252.0
    network 192.168.7.0
#broadcast 192.168.7.3
    gateway 192.168.7.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

but it didn't help.

I don't know what else should I do. Please help.

Additional useful infos:

Beagle Bone Black:
ifconfig

```
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ce:39:f3:4a:c7:94  
          inet addr:192.168.7.2  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Mask:255.255.255.252
          inet6 addr: fe80::cc39:f3ff:fe4a:c794/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:608 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:375 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:57484 (57.4 KB)  TX bytes:63078 (63.0 KB)
```

route

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.7.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 usb0
192.168.7.0     *               255.255.255.252 U     0      0        0 usb0
```

uname -a

```
Linux arm 3.8.13-bone28 #1 SMP Fri Sep 13 03:12:24 UTC 2013 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

/etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
#domain localdomain
#search localdomain
#nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

PC:

ifconfig

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:17:31:8d:6a:a6  
          inet Adresse:141.3.81.154  Bcast:141.3.83.255  Maske:255.255.252.0
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::217:31ff:fe8d:6aa6/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:30732 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5888 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:7266589 (7.2 MB)  TX-Bytes:1286462 (1.2 MB)
          Interrupt:19

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse 00:04:75:ca:98:ee  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX-Bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:21 Basisadresse:0xe400

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  Hardware Adresse c8:a0:30:ac:2c:95  
          inet Adresse:192.168.7.1  Bcast:192.168.7.3  Maske:255.255.255.252
          inet6-Adresse: fe80::caa0:30ff:feac:2c95/64 Gültigkeitsbereich:Verbindung
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metrik:1
          RX packets:418 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:1000
          RX-Bytes:45704 (45.7 KB)  TX-Bytes:88161 (88.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Lokale Schleife  
          inet Adresse:127.0.0.1  Maske:255.0.0.0
          inet6-Adresse: ::1/128 Gültigkeitsbereich:Maschine
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metrik:1
          RX packets:840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:840 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          Kollisionen:0 Sendewarteschlangenlänge:0
          RX-Bytes:142988 (142.9 KB)  TX-Bytes:142988 (142.9 KB)
```

route

```
Ziel            Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         i60-gw-int.ipr. 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
141.3.80.0      *               255.255.252.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
link-local      *               255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth2
192.168.7.0     *               255.255.255.252 U     1      0        0 eth2
```

uname -a

```
Linux i60p354 3.2.0-56-generic #86-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 09:20:45 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What can be important - PC, which share Internet with BBB works in the University network, which is far more complicated than normal home network - could that cause problems with DNS resolving? Whats important yet - if I set a nameserver that makes sense in resolv.conf.d/head (which is simply up and running like 8.8.8.8) and type ping google.com the maschine computes for some time and than returns error unknown host. If I set a nonsense adress, which surely doesn't work (ie 123.123.123.123) error is being returned immediately.

Comment: With a (not back) BB, your commands works with no error. I just replaced nameserver 127.0.0.1 with nameserver <ip of my dns>, and hostname resolution worked...

Answer (score 5):

I got this working by adding the interface on my host (Fedora 20) to the trusted zone. I'm embarrassed to say I don't know what this really does though. I looked at the raw IP tables output and didn't see any mention of this interface, only some chains by zone. Anyway, check out your host and see what could be preventing IP forwarding. I'm guessing ping works because the defaults are more relaxed for ICMP traffic. Also, I think you have one typo in the above, the netmask for usb0 should be 255.255.255.252. Thank you for posting what you did, this would have been way more painful without it.

Comment: This certainly helps.

Answer (score 1):

For the issue of Connection Manager overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf`,a hoaky solution is to protect the file (`chmod 444` doesn't seem to be honored):

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

reboot to verify that the change holds using 'reboot'

To unprotect the file later:

```
chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf
```

It was either do this or play the `/etc/init.d/connman` game of refreshing (ie. overwrite) `resolve.conf` at boot time after connman.

Answer (score 1):

To share system(i tried ubuntu & fedora) WiFi internet with beaglebone black (through ethernet)with Debian wheezy installed follow this method.

On PC
click on network icon>vpn connections>configure vpn>ethernet
click +Add

name the connection beagledhcp or anything u like

change IPV4 settings to automatic dhcp

additional DNS servers to 192.168.7.2(IP of beaglebone)

click save

click on network icon>vpn connections>configure vpn>ethernet

click +Add

name the connection beagleshared or anything u like

change IPV4 settings to "shared to other computers"

click save(2 connections may be automatically established when LAN cable and USB cable 
of beaglebone are connected to the PC.u can edit these connections also)

connect the board to the PC(LAN & USB)

Open the terminal and type

```
[dawn@localhost ~]$ ssh root@192.168.7.2
Debian GNU/Linux 7

BeagleBoard.org BeagleBone Debian Image 2014-04-23

Support/FAQ: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian
Last login: Sat Aug  2 19:54:25 2014 from linux.local
root@beaglebone:~#



   vi /etc/network/interfaces
```

add these lines to file:to set static IP for beaglebone Ethernet(eth0)

```
    auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.42.0.69
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.42.0.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.8.9
```

save the file

```
/etc/init.d/networking restart
```

do ifconfig to know the changes

ping 8.8.8.8

done

if u hav any doubt mail me:dawnpaulfacebook@gmail.com

Comment: The part about "additional DNS servers to 192.168.7.2(IP of beaglebone)" has nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

For me, an important part of the puzzle was also to run these commands on the host machine that the BBB is connected to:

```
iptables --flush            
iptables --table nat --flush
iptables --delete-chain     
iptables --table nat --delete-chain
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface enp8s0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface enp8s0 -j ACCEPT
```

And maybe also this:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Answer (score 0):

Type in a terminal of the server/gateway:

## arp -s "$IP" "$MAC" pub

Where, $MAC is the hardware address of the linux gateway box's Ethernet controller. You can find it by running ifconfig and checking the ether property of your Ethernet interface.   $IP is the ip of the usb port in the same server/gateway that is connected to the beagle.

:)